# I am getting error in deploying Deep learning model using Flask

Tags: machine-learning, flask, deep-learning, deployment, data-science

```
type here
from flask import Flask , redirect , url_for , render_template, request
import pickle
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np
from tensorflow import keras
from keras.models import load_model

from tensorflow.keras.preprocessing.image import load_img , img_to_array

app = Flask(__name__)

model = load_model('9366_9660model.h5')

key_list =\['Apple___Apple_scab', 'Apple___Black_rot', 'Apple___Cedar_apple_rust', 'Apple___healthy', 'Blueberry___healthy', 'Cherry\_(including_sour)___Powdery_mildew', 'Cherry_(including_sour)\_\__healthy', 'Corn_(maize)\_\__Cercospora_leaf_spot Gray_leaf_spot', 'Corn_(maize)\__Common_rust_', 'Corn(maize)\_\__Northern_Leaf_Blight', 'Corn_(maize)_healthy', 'Grape___Black_rot', 'Grape___Esca_(Black_Measles)', 'Grape___Leaf_blight(Isariopsis_Leaf_Spot)', 'Grape___healthy', 'Orange___Haunglongbing(Citrus_greening)', 'Peach___Bacterial_spot', 'Peach___healthy', 'Pepper,\_bell___Bacterial_spot', 'Pepper,\_bell___healthy', 'Potato___Early_blight', 'Potato___Late_blight', 'Potato___healthy', 'Raspberry___healthy', 'Soybean___healthy', 'Squash___Powdery_mildew', 'Strawberry___Leaf_scorch', 'Strawberry___healthy', 'Tomato___Bacterial_spot', 'Tomato___Early_blight', 'Tomato___Late_blight', 'Tomato___Leaf_Mold', 'Tomato___Septoria_leaf_spot', 'Tomato___Spider_mites Two-spotted_spider_mite', 'Tomato___Target_Spot', 'Tomato___Tomato_Yellow_Leaf_Curl_Virus', 'Tomato___Tomato_mosaic_virus', 'Tomato___healthy'\`]`

val_list = \[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33, 34, 35, 36, 37\]

def predict_model(path):
image = load_img(path , target_size=(299,299))
x = img_to_array(image)
x = x/225
x = np.expand_dims(x , axis=0)

    images = np.vstack([x])
    pred_res = model.predict(images , batch_size=10)
    pred_res = np.argmax(pred_res[0])
    posi = val_list.index(pred_res)
    value = key_list[posi]
    return value

@app.route('/')
def home():
return render_template('index.html')

@app.route('/predict' , method = \['POST ' , 'GET'\]  )
def predict():
if __name__ == 'POST':
img = request.files('imge_file')
img_path = "static/" + img.filename
img.save(img_path)

        pred = predict_model(img_path)
    
    return render_template ('index.html' , prediction = pred , image_path = img_path

if __name__ =='__main__':
app.run(debug =True)
```

Getting this error

```
PS C:\\ML deployment\> python main.py
2023-04-09 18:01:41.169014: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:193\] This TensorFlow binary is optimized with oneAPI Deep Neural Network Library (oneDNN) to use the following CPU instructions in performance-critical operations:  AVX2
To enable them in other operations, rebuild TensorFlow with the appropriate compiler flags.
2023-04-09 18:01:41.173056: I tensorflow/core/common_runtime/process_util.cc:146\] Creating new thread pool with default inter op setting: 2. Tune using inter_op_parallelism_threads for best performance.
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\\ML deployment\\main.py", line 37, in \<module\>
def predict():
File "C:\\Users\\mohit\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1315, in decorator
self.add_url_rule(rule, endpoint, f, \*\*options)
File "C:\\Users\\mohit\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 98, in wrapper_func
return f(self, \*args, \*\*kwargs)
File "C:\\Users\\mohit\\anaconda3\\lib\\site-packages\\flask\\app.py", line 1275, in add_url_rule
rule = self.url_rule_class(rule, methods=methods, \*\*options)
TypeError: __init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'method'
```

Answer (score 1):

As for the error, you use undefined argument for flask route.
You should use "methods" instead of "method", so the decorator should look like that:

```
@app.route('/predict' , methods = \['POST ' , 'GET'\]  )
```